# Mostrar dato concreto de array con objetos

Tags: php

Quiero mostrar un dato concreto de un array, tengo el siguiente código y estoy intentando que la función `imprimirAlumnoConcreto` me imprima un alumno concreto que yo le indique pasada por la variable `$nombre`.

Al intentar buscar el alumno me imprime el siguiente error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Alumno as array

La estructura del array es la siguiente :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(Alumno)#1 (4) {
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(5) "Alumno1"
    ["apellido":"Alumno":private]=>
    string(7) "Apellido1"
  }
}
```

Y la funcion con la que estoy intentando imprimir un dato concreto :

```
function imprimirAlumnoConcreto($nombre) {

    foreach($this->alumnos as $key=>$value){

        if($value["nombre"] == $nombre){

            echo $value->getNombre() . " ";
            echo $value->getApellido() . " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario recurrir a conversiones del objeto, mientras menos se manipulen las cosas mejor, además el código revela que necesitas recurrir a los *getter* para obtener otro tipo de información del objeto.

Por tanto, puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
$nombre="Nombre1";

foreach ($this->alumnos as $alumno){
    if ($nombre == $alumno->nombre) {
        echo $alumno->getNombre() . " ";
        echo $alumno->getApellido() . " ";
        break;
    }
}
```

Asumo que el `var_dump` que muestras equivale a `$this->alumnos` (ver Fiddle con una reproducción del problema funcionando).

**Nótese** que aquí salimos del bucle con `break` en cuanto se encuentra el dato (si se encuentra), pues no tendría sentido seguir recorriendo el array de objetos si ya se encontró lo que se buscaba.

---

#### Fiddle

Puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/BRVKS49675)**</kbd> en línea y hacer pruebas sobre el código.

Answer (score 1):

El error es que `$this->alumnos` es un json y tienes que convertirlo con [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) en un array:

Ejemplo funcionando:

```
// json
$alumnos = '{"nombre":"Nombre1", "apellido":"Apellido1"}';

// lo convertimos en un array asociativo (noten el true)
$alumnos = json_decode($alumnos, true);

// Paso el primer parámetro $alumnos, solo por demostración
function imprimirAlumnoConcreto($alumnos, $nombre) {

    foreach( $alumnos as $key => $value) {

        if( $value == $nombre){

            echo 'La clave "'.$key .'" tiene el valor: "'.$value.'"';
        }
    }
}

imprimirAlumnoConcreto($alumnos, 'Nombre1');
```

<kbd>**[Ver demo online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c627677910b2ab644ec4b4aaff4ce0c95fc2d13d)**</kbd>